# Replace only whole word matches in a string

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, word-boundary

I would like to replace just complete words using php

Example :
If I have

```
$text = "Hello hellol hello, Helloz";
```

and I use

```
$newtext = str_replace("Hello",'NEW',$text);
```

The new text should look like

> NEW hello1 hello, Helloz

PHP returns

> NEW hello1 hello, NEWz

Thanks.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You want to use regular expressions. The `\b` matches a word boundary.

```
$text = preg_replace('/\bHello\b/', 'NEW', $text);
```

---

If `$text` contains UTF-8 text, you'll have to add the Unicode modifier "u", so that non-latin characters are not misinterpreted as word boundaries:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\bHello\b/u', 'NEW', $text);
```

Comment: This matches mother in mother-in-law 

Comment: A fix for the above case might be here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39685053/129202

Comment: what if we want to replace same world from whole sting more than once

Answer (score 8):

**multiple word in string replaced by this**

```
    $String = 'Team Members are committed to delivering quality service for all buyers and sellers.';
    echo $String;
    echo "<br>";
    $String = preg_replace(array('/\bTeam\b/','/\bfor\b/','/\ball\b/'),array('Our','to','both'),$String);
    echo $String;
    Result: Our Members are committed to delivering quality service to both buyers and sellers.
```

Answer (score 2):

**Array** replacement list: In case your replacement strings are substituting each other, you need [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

```
$pairs = ["one"=>"two", "two"=>"three", "three"=>"one"];

$r = preg_replace_callback(
    "/\w+/",                           # only match whole words
    function($m) use ($pairs) {
        if (isset($pairs[$m[0]])) {     # optional: strtolower
            return $pairs[$m[0]];      
        }
        else {
            return $m[0];              # keep unreplaced
        }
    },
    $source
);
```

Obviously / for efficiency `/\w+/` could be replaced with a key-list `/\b(one|two|three)\b/i`.

Comment: you have a syntax error , replace the last braces with parenthesis of `preg_replace`

Comment: also, the `if (isset($pairs[$m[0]])` doesnot have the cosing parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking exactly for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx](https://t-regx.com) library, that quotes `$` or `\` characters while replacing

```
<?php
$text = pattern('\bHello\b')->replace($text)->all()->with('NEW');
```