# How to replace just complete words in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP string replace match whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426265/php-string-replace-match-whole-word)

What I want to do is to replace Tomato with Apple for example.
The Probleim I'm running in is:

when the string contains "Tomatos" (mention the s) it will replace Tomato and leafe me with a string "Apples" (again mention the s).

Because "Tomato" != "Tomatos" (...s) it shall NOT replace.

Which PHP funktion is good for this task?
I tried the str_replace function but it seems like it isn't possible to archive my task with it.

---

€

The words are seperated with ",".

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426265/php-string-replace-match-whole-word

Answer (score 2):

preg_replace. You can search for a regular expression, like `\bTomato\b`, which means `whole word Tomato`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use str_replace try adding commas either side of the Tomato. Then it should only replace the word Tomato.

Otherwise you'll need preg_replace