# Trying to extract keywords from a website PHP (OOP)

Tags: php, extract, keyword

haha, I still have the problem of keywords, but this is a code that I'm creating.

Is a poor code but is my creation:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animalia';
Keys($url);
function Keys($url) { 
$listanegra = array("a", "ante", "bajo", "con", "contra", "de", "desde", "mediante", "durante", "hasta", "hacia", "para", "por", "que", "qué", "cuán", "cuan", "los", "las", "una", "unos", "unas", "donde", "dónde", "como", "cómo", "cuando", "porque", "por", "para", "según", "sin", "tras", "con", "mas", "más", "pero", "del"); 

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $webhtml = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
    $webhtml = $webhtml ->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $webhtml = strip_tags($webhtml);
    $webhtml = explode(" ", $webhtml);

    foreach($listanegra as $key=> $ln) {
    $webhtml = str_replace($ln, " ", $webhtml);
    }
    $palabras = str_word_count ("$webhtml", 1 ); 
    $frq = array_count_values ($palabras); 
    $frq = asort($frq);
    $ffrq = count($frq);
$i=1;
while ($i < $ffrq) {
    print $frqq[$i];
    print '<br />';
    $i++;
}
}
?>
```

The code trying extract keywords of a website. Extracts the first paragraph of a web, and deletes the words of the variable "$listanegra". Next, counts the repeat words and saves all words in a "array". After i call the array, and this show me the words.

The problem is... the code it's not functional =(.

When i use the code, this shows blank.

Could help me finish my code?. Was recommending me to using "tf-idf", but I will use it later.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally deleted the first part: Hi again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe this is what you were trying to do:

```
$url = 'http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animalia';

$words = Keys($url);

/// do your database stuff with $words


function Keys($url)
{
    $listanegra = array('a', 'ante', 'bajo', 'con', 'contra', 'de', 'desde', 'mediante', 'durante', 'hasta', 'hacia', 'para', 'por', 'que', 'qué', 'cuán', 'cuan', 'los', 'las', 'una', 'unos', 'unas', 'donde', 'dónde', 'como', 'cómo', 'cuando', 'porque', 'por', 'para', 'según', 'sin', 'tras', 'con', 'mas', 'más', 'pero', 'del');

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $webhtml = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
    $webhtml = $webhtml->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $webhtml = strip_tags($webhtml);
    $webhtml = explode(' ', $webhtml);

    $palabras = array();
    foreach($webhtml as $word)
    {
        $word = strtolower(trim($word, ' .,!?()')); // remove trailing special chars and spaces
        if (!in_array($word, $listanegra))
        {
            $palabras[] = $word;
        }
    }
    $frq = array_count_values($palabras);
    asort($frq);
    return implode(' ', array_keys($frq));
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, I have one more doubt, how i can save the words ($word) in a new variable: $keywords, and after show the words directly of the variable $keywords? Best regards

Comment: I apologize, but I don't understand your question. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Of course, I need to extract keywords from a website and save them to a database.

To store them in the database, I need to save the keywords in the variable $keywords. Then a function takes care of adding the variable $keywords in the field "keywords" of the db

Comment: aahh ok, you you don't want it printed out but rather put into a variable to store in database. Are you wanting the word and count value for each word stored as well? If so the variable would have to be serialized. If just the words I can just make a space separated list.

Comment: Really i need only the words. How i can create the list with the keywords?.

Comment: see my edited code. Function will return a space separated list of the words.

Comment: Thanks! The code extracts the keywords, but ignores the $listanegra. The values ​​of the blacklist, should be eliminated in order to have higher quality keywords.

Thanks for all!!

Comment: if (!in_array($word, $listanegra)) checks to see if the word is not in the blacklist array, then it adds the word to $words

Comment: I added the words 'en', 'la' and 'se' in listanegra, but were added in the keywords.

I try the old foreach, but does not work, and deletes all keywords

Comment: I just tested, I added 'y' and 'en' to blacklist and it removed them. I think you are incorrectly adding the words to the array. Please post what you are doing.

Comment: This is an example of the $listanegra = array('se', 'es', 'en', 'la'); I use the next code: if (empty($keywords)){ $keywords = Keys($url); } to call the function Keys($url).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20482/discussion-between-cryptic-and-psilvestre)

Answer (score 0):

Your server should show the errors if you are testing :
add this after

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

that way you will see the error:
Array to string conversion on line 24 *(line 19 if you don't put the 5 new lines)*

here are some errors i found 4 functions are not used as they should str_replace, str_word_count , asort , array_count_values.

Using **[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)** is a little tricky. Trying to find and remove a removes all the "a" in the text even in "animal". (str_replace("a","animal") => nmal)
this link should be usefull : **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426265/php-string-replace-match-whole-word)**

**[asort](http://php.net/asort)** return true or false so doing just:

```
asort($frq);
```

will sort the values in alphabetical order. $frq returns the result of **[array_count_values](http://php.net/array_count_values)** --> $frq = array($word1=>word1_count , ...)
the value here is the number of times the word is used so when later you have :

```
 print $**frq**[$i]; // you have  print $frqq[$i]; in your code
```

the result will be empty since the index of this array are the words and the values the number of time the words appear in the text.

Also with **[str_word_count](http://php.net/str_word_count)** you must be really careful, since you are reading Hispanic text and text can have numbers you shoudl use this

```
str_word_count($string,1,'áéíóúüñ1234567890');
```

The code i would suggest :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);



$url = 'http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animalia';
Keys($url);
function Keys($url) { 
$listanegra = array("a", "ante", "bajo", "con", "contra", "de", "desde", "mediante", "durante", "hasta", "hacia", "para", "por", "que", "qué", "cuán", "cuan", "los", "las", "una", "unos", "unas", "donde", "dónde", "como", "cómo", "cuando", "porque", "por", "para", "según", "sin", "tras", "con", "mas", "más", "pero", "del"); 

$html=file_get_contents($url);

    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8"); 
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
     $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $webhtml = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');


    $webhtml = $webhtml ->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $webhtml = strip_tags($webhtml);
    print_r ($webhtml);
    $webhtml = explode(" ", $webhtml);


   // $webhtml = str_replace($listanegra, " ", $webhtml); str_replace() accepts array

    foreach($listanegra as $key=> $ln) {

    $webhtml = preg_replace('/\b'.$ln.'\b/u', ' ', $webhtml);
    }

    $palabras = str_word_count(implode(" ",$webhtml), 1, 'áéíóúüñ1234567890');

    sort($palabras);

    $frq = array_count_values ($palabras);


foreach($frq as $index=>$value) {
    print "the word <strong>$index</strong>  was used <strong>$value</strong> times";
    print '<br />';

}
}
?>
```

Was really painfull trying to figure out the special chars issues