# Whole word replacement in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace whole word in php. I found a code from the link below
[PHP string replace match whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426265/php-string-replace-match-whole-word)

I took code sample below from the above link.

```
$text = preg_replace('/\bHello\b/', 'NEW', $text);
```

but it is not working for me.
I have a string like

```
3 OR ( 2 AND CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:2 ) OR 4
```

After replace 2 using above code it becomes

```
3 OR ( Name = 'LAST WEEK' AND CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:Name = 'LAST WEEK' ) OR 4.
```

2 is replace for "LAST_N_DAYS:2" string also. I want to replace only 2 alone. If it is with any word it should not be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace 2 with NEW:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\s2\s/',' NEW ',$test);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working but it is replacing with extra space. for example if str = 'this is 2 only'. and i am replacing 2=4, then the result is coming like 'this is 4only'. actually '2 ' is replacing.

Comment: Then put a space after 4 in the replacement string like I did with ' NEW '

Answer (score 0):

If you only wants to replace first occurrence then add a limit:

```
// pattern, replacement, string, limit
$text = preg_replace('#2#U', 'NEW', $text, 1);
```

Or you can use below:

```
$text = preg_replace('#2\s(AND)#', 'NEW $1', $text);
```

Comment: This replaces all occurences of 2 with NEW. And in the second case only the first 2. The user wants to replace any standalone 2 in the string with something else.

Answer (score 0):

you can simple use

```
str_replace('2', "Name = 'LAST WEEK'", $string);
```

Comment: In this case all 2 will be replaced. for example $str = '2 and 12'. if we replace 2=4, then output will be '4 and 14' not '4 and 12'.