# pattern should be replaced only when it matches a particular word in the whole string

Tags: php

```
$text=" ma mee ma mee meena mia meenaùs";
```

**$text is a string** with hundreds of words,above is a short illustration.

what i want is i want to check if the $text contains '**mee**' if yes than replace mee with " "(i.e. space).

i am using `preg_replace` for the same but as obvious it searches for the pattern `mee` and replaces it with space even when the `$text` has meena.

in short i want the replacement only when the `$text` value is mee not meena.how to achieve this using **PREG_REPLACE** or related function?
Thanks in advance

```
$text = preg_replace("mee","", $text);
```

**expected output:**  "ma ma meena mia meenaùs"
there seem to some encoding issue as it is not working for meenaùs

Comment: Regex should be avoided and only be used when there are no reasonable other alternatives.

Comment: Have you considered $foo === $bar ?

Answer (score 3):

As a regular expression it would be `^mee$` which you would use with `preg_replace` like so:

```
$text = preg_replace("/^mee$/","", $text);
```

`^` matches the start of the string
`$` matches the end of the string

This is quite a simple replacement to do however so it may be more efficient to do it without using regular expressions.

---

Ok seeing as you've changed the question the answer for the new question would be:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\bmee\b/","", $text);
```

This should match the pattern `mee` where it is a word on it's own and not part of another word.

Comment: what if $text is a string with hundred of words.

Comment: @user2935196 well that requires a different answer.  The regular expression for that would be `\bmee\b` as `\b` matches a word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($text == "mee")
    $text = " ";
```

That's it.

If you want the word `"mee"` changed in a string that contains this word many times, use `$text = preg_replace('/\bmee\b/', ' ', $text);`.

Comment: this is not what i want ,i want to perform this using preg_replace or related functions

Comment: Please see my comment under your question

Comment: @user2935196 preg_replace will be like 1000x slower than this. Still AeroX has answered what you want (which, imo, is not the right answer)

Comment: @user2935196 Regex is not really the right tool for this job. The simple compare and replace example given by Thomas is far more efficient.

Comment: what if $text is a string with hundreds of words.

Comment: @user2935196 you mean `"ma mee ma mee mia"` should be replaced with `"ma   ma   mia"` ?

Comment: @ThomasRuiz ya right ma mee ma mee meena mia should be "ma ma meena mia"

Comment: @user2935196 check out this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426265/php-string-replace-match-whole-word?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You may go for a combination of `preg_match` and `preg_replace`.

Check the string for the exact matched text first:

```
    <?php
    $text=" ma mee ma mee meena mia";
    echo $text."<br/>";
    $key = "mee";
    $rep_text = "YES";

    $text = preg_replace("/\b".$key."\b/u", $rep_text, $text);
    echo $text."<br/>";

    ?>
```

Try this.

Comment: Check it out, I have edited the answer, its working now... you can check it here also http://phptester.net/

Comment: its failing because of a non english word,see my updated question.

Comment: Edited the code , Try again :)