# Replace words with words regex php

Tags: php, regex

I need to be able to search a string and replace words like 'me', 'my', 'i' and replace them with words like 'you', and 'your'. Basically I need to be able to change the subjects possession.

#### Example

```
User input: "Can you remind me to feed my dog tonight?"
Response  : "Sure I can remind you to: feed your dog tonight"
```

Where "remind me" is a command so that is ignored but 'my' should be changed to your. However what I have will changed every collection of the characters "m" and "y" to "your". So words like `astronomy` is now `astronoyour`. Which I don't want.

```
public static function userToServer($string){
   $pos = array(' me '=>'you', ' i '=>'you','we'=>'we','us'=>'you','you'=>' i ', ' my '=>'your');
   foreach($pos as $key => $value){
      if(strpos($string, $key) !== false){
          $result = str_replace ($key, $value, $string );
          print_r($result);
          return  $result;
      }
   }
  return null;
}
public static function parse($string, $commands){
  foreach($commands as $c){
     if(stripos($string,$c) !== false){
        $params = explode($c, $string);
        $com[$c] =$params[1];
     }
   }
   if(isset($params)){
     foreach($com as $key => $value){
       if($key ==='remind me to'){
          //$user->addEventToCalender($value);
          //echo $value;
          echo 'Okay, I will remind you to '.String::userToServer($value);
       }
     }
   }
}
```

And example output from using the above functions

```
Using $_GET['input'] as $input
Original: Will you remind me to secure funds for my business
Response: Okay, I will remind you to secure funds for my byouiness
```

I'm sure I am going to have to create my own way to figure this out, but I figured I'd ask because I know regex is a great tool, and I am probably overlooking the solution.

#### Semi working demo

This demo url shows the current code that I am using and will be updated as answers come in. Please feel free to look around :)

Direct link to the string class in question: http://api.austinkregel.com/butler/string-class

Comment: you need to consider word boundaries, so you should look at `preg_repalce()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


  function userToServer($string){

      $in=array('#\bcat\b#','#\bdog\b#');
      $out=array('fish','frog');
      $string=preg_replace($in,$out,$string);  
      return $string;
    }


   echo userToServer("cat eat dog but not doge");  //fish eat frog but not doge


?>
```

Comment: So would you not recommend using a key value system like I am using? (Current code is shown on the website)

Comment: its not as efficient to call preg_repace X times when you only need to call it once. you could keep your original array and use it to build the other 2 arrays if you like

Comment: yours does not work because you are returning inside the loop, so only one replacement will ever be made

Comment: I updated the code accordingly and I am still not getting the proper change. This new update actually takes out the word entirely.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. I was missing a single instance of "you"

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PHP string replace match whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426265/php-string-replace-match-whole-word)

In that link, it shows you how to use `preg_replace`.

You can use something like this:

`$phrase = preg_replace('/\bmy\b/i', 'your', $phrase);`

*This code is not tested, and you may have to make some changes*

Comment: I am trying this, and it's not replacing the words. Click the link I listed above to see the code I am using and a demo

Comment: dont do `if(preg_match('/\b'.&#36;key.'\b/', &#36;string )!== false){`

Comment: It still is not replacing the words.