# strtr is replacing in an unexpected way

Tags: php, replace, str-replace, strtr

strtr is replacing in an unexpected way. Please take a look at my code.

```
$stringX = "Do you remember me?";

strtr($stringX, array("you" => "me", "me" => "you"));
```

Expected output: Do me remember you.

Actual output: Do me reyoumber you.

How do I get the expected output?

Comment: have a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426265/php-string-replace-match-whole-word

Comment: @Jeff And that takes off the whole point of replacing me and you at the same time.

Comment: @Narendra Sisodia Why did you deleted your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$stringX = "Do you remember me?";

strtr($stringX, array("you" => "me", " me" => " you"));
```

Note the space before `me`!!!

**NOTE: This will work only in this specific case and might produce unexpected output for other strings!**

Comment: Well, just keep in mind that this solution is very specific and will only work with this case. As soon as another word that starts with 'me' is added, it'll have a similar problem again.

Comment: It wouldn't won't if remember is member, but if you do both spaces in front and back, and what if it's me? without a space?