# How to make word boundary \b not match on dashes

Tags: python, regex

I simplified my code to the specific problem I am having.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\bword\b')
result = pattern.sub(lambda x: "match", "-word- word")
```

I am getting

```
'-match- match'
```

but I want

```
'-word- match'
```

edit:

Or for the string `"word -word-"`

I want

```
"match -word-"
```

Comment: These are hyphens, not dashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` basically denotes a word boundary on characters other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` which includes spaces as well. Surround `word` with negative lookarounds to ensure there is no non-space character after and before it:

```
re.compile(r'(?<!\S)word(?!\S)')
```

Answer (score 10):

What you need is a negative lookbehind.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!-)\bword\b')
result = pattern.sub(lambda x: "match", "-word- word")
```

To cite the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `(?<!...)`
>       Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a match for ....

So this will only match, if the word-break `\b` is not preceded with a minus sign `-`.

If you need this for the end of the string you'll have to use a negative lookahead which will look like this: `(?!-)`. The complete regular expression will then result in: `(?<!-)\bword(?!-)\b`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of word boundaries, you could also match the character before and after the word with a `(\s|^)` and `(\s|$)` pattern.

**Breakdown**: `\s` matches every whitespace character, which seems to be what you are trying to achieve, as you are excluding the dashes. The `^` and `$` ensure that if the word is either the first or last in the string(ie. no character before or after) those are matched too.

Your code would become something like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\s|^)(word)(\s|$)')
result = pattern.sub(r"\1match\3", "-word- word")
```

Because this solution uses character classes such as `\s`, it means that those could be easily replaced or extended. For example if  you wanted your words to be delimited by spaces or commas, your pattern would become something like this: `r'(,|\s|^)(word)(,|\s|$)'`.