# PHP preg_replace: highlight whole words matching a key in case/diacritic-insensitive way

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to highlight single words or phrases matching the $key (whole words, not substrings) in an UTF-8 $text. Such match has to be both case-insensitive and diacritic-insensitive. The highlighted text must remain as it was (including uppercase/lowercase characters and diacritical marks, if present).

The following expression achieved half the goal:

```
$text = preg_replace( "/\b($key)\b/i", '<div class="highlight">$1</div>', $text );
```

It's case insensitive and matches whole words but won't highlight the $text portions matching $key if such portions contain diacritical marks not present in $key.
E.g. I'd like to have "Björn Källström" highlighted in $text passing $key = "bjorn kallstrom".

Any brilliant idea (using preg_replace or another PHP function) is welcome.

Comment: A font tag with a class, it's a bit steampunk.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: ok, I replaced the "font" tag with a "div" ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426265/php-string-replace-match-whole-word

Comment: @Jason Grim: no, I don't think it's a duplicate: the question you linked does not consider diacritical marks at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea consists to transform the keys to patterns replacing all problematic characters with a character class:

```
$corr = ['a' => '[aàáâãäå]', 'o' => '[oòóôõö]',/* etc. */];

$key = 'bjorn kallstrom';

$pattern = '/\b' . strtr($key, $corr) . '\b/iu';

$text = preg_replace($pattern, '<em class="highlight">$0</em>', $text);
```

Note that since you are dealing with unicode characters, you need to use the u modifier to avoid unexpected behaviours in particular with word boundaries.

If your keys already contain accented characters, convert them to ascii first:

```
$key = 'björn kallstrom';
$key = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $key);
```

*(If you obtain `?` in place of letters, that means that your locales are set to C or POSIX. In this case change them to en_US.UTF-8, or another one available in your system. see [setlocale](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php))*

Also take a look at the very useful intl classes: [Normalizer](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) and [Transliterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php).

Notice: if you have several keys to highlight, do all in one shot. Sort the array by length (the longest first using `mb_strlen`), use `array_map` to transliterate the keys to ascii, and implode the array with `|`. The goal is to obtain the pattern: `'/\b(?:' . implode('|', $keys) . ')\b/iu'` with `bj[oòóôõö]rn k[aàáâãäå]llstr[oòóôõö]m` before `bj[oòóôõö]rn` alone (for instance).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with just a function call, you will have to implement it.

1. extract the text from the HTML (`$document->documentElement->textContent`)
2. split the text into words and normalize them - keep the originals (`$words[$normalized][] = $original`) - basically this provides you with a list of variants for each normalized word.
3. split and normalize the search query
4. compile RegEx patterns from the search query to match `((word1_v1|word1_v2)\s*(word2_v1|word2_v2))u` and validate `(^(word1_v1|word1_v2)\s*(word2_v1|word2_v2)$)u`
5. Iterate over the text nodes in you HTML document `$xpath->evaluate('//text()')`
6. Use `preg_split()` to separate the text by the search strings, capture the delimiters (search matches)
7. Iterate over that list and add them as text nodes if the are not a search string match, otherwise add the HTML structure for a highlight
8. remove the original text node.