# Need to translate words in string by using str_replace or any other way

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

Im having a XML feed with english characters which i need to translate to my language. Problem is its not transtlating exact strings but every similiar word.

Is there any way to translate only full strings and not everything inside words?

Example:

```
$string = "Red Cell is very good. Condition is new. But nobody buys it.";
$words = ["Red Cell", "Condition", "no", "Red", "new"];
$translations = ["Red Cell", "Stav", "ne", "Červený", "nový"];

$string = str_replace($words, $translations, $string);
```

**What i get**:

**Červený Cell** is very good. Stav is **ne**vý. But **ne**body buys it.

---

**What i want**:

**Red Cell** is very good. **Stav** is **nový**. But **nobody** buys it.

---

Is there any way to translate exact strings and not everything that contains that words?

Comment: Watch this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426265/php-string-replace-match-whole-word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to build an associative array (`$pairs`) with the words as keys and the translations as values, and then to build a search pattern with all words in an alternation:

```
$string = "Red Cell is very good. Condition is new. But nobody buys it.";
$words = ["Red Cell", "Condition", "no", "Red", "new"];
$translations = ["Red Cell", "Stav", "ne", "Červený", "nový"];

$pairs = array_combine($words, $translations);
krsort($pairs);

$pattern = '~\b(?:' . implode('|', array_keys($pairs)) . ')\b~u';

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) use ($pairs) {
    return $pairs[$m[0]];
}, $string);

echo $result;
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/EgrVV)

To ensure that the longest string is tested first (between for example "Red Cell" and "Red"), the words in the pattern are sorted in a reverse order.

The advantage of `preg_replace_callback` with a single pattern and replacement parameters over `str_replace` with arrays, is that the string is processed only once when `str_replace` will parse the entire string once per word (it prevents circular replacements). Also, since the search parameter is a regex pattern, you can use word-boundaries to be sure that a word isn't cut in the middle.

Comment: Thanks for your help and answer. Anyway.. i found a problem and i am not able to solve it. Ill be happy for any hint.

When it comes to translate regular sentences like "eBook reader batteries", there is no problem. But now I came across translating "Charger | AC Adapter for" which spits string by "|" as OR logic. I need regex pattern to ignore pipe and take whole string. I tried to put "\" before pipe. But it doesnt work. I also tried this "Charger [\|] AC Adapter for" but its giving me "Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\robbie.php on line 147" error. Thanks for any help

Comment: @SophiaTibbers: when you build the pattern, change `array_keys($pairs)` to `array_map(function ($i) {return preg_quote($i, '~');}, array_keys($pairs))`. `preg_quote` will escape regex special characters like the pipe.

Comment: Do not escape these characters in the `$words` array, because the matched strings are not escaped.

Comment: You are the best sir. Thanks alot.